# PhP best practices & real world examples for further learning

Tags: php

I learned php from various video tutorials (lynda, phpacadmey) and my php programming is good to go.
But now i want to learn more. Various books seems boring ...as mainly these books a are for beginners
I want to learn from various examples and real world stuff not from basics
Pls suugest me any nice source

Comment: You can learn best from solving given problem(s).

Comment: bt problems from where...temme any src

Comment: You'll find that most PHP books are written for outdated versions of PHP, and/or contain very bad coding practices. Be sure to read a LOT about secure coding in PHP before you go out into the field. It's a jungle out there, and some of the books are pirhannas and man-eating plants in disguise.

Comment: One way to learn is to answer questions on SO! It's full of real world examples/questions and advice. Search though some older questions, find a new solution, learn from what others have posted, test it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions:

1. Start reading some opensource PHP code and learn from that. I would suggest reading the [Symfony](http://symfony.com) code.
2. Make yourself a project, for example a forum, some kind of website, etc. that you are interested in. Might be some idea of yours that you would like to code. It doesn't matter if the idea is complex - take something that seems "too big", and learn from that.

I learned several programming languages just by having sparetime projects that  initially seemed too complex for my skills at that point.
Also, doing that will cause you to use what you've learned so far and will face you with some real problems and not just the "I wanna learn more"-issue.

Additionally, there are some intersting Github projects that you might be able to learn from: [Explore Github - PHP](https://github.com/languages/PHP)